# Issues with rendering HTML from a JSON string with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am attempting to take HTML markup within a JSON string and render it as functioning HTML with AngularJS, using $sce.trustAsHtml. I'm pretty confident that the problem is an issue with my markup, as it was not entirely clear to me how to go about pulling information from my JSON rather than putting the intended HTML straight into my controller, as shown on the Angular website.

From my details.html partial:

```
    <div ng-bind-html="$sce.trustAsHtml(whichItem.item1.widget)"></div>
```

From my controller.js file:

```
hashControllers.controller('DetailsController', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams', '$sce', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $sce) {
  $http.get('js/list_data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.hash = data;
    $scope.$sce = $sce;
    $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;

    if ($routeParams.itemId > 0) {
      $scope.prevItem = Number($routeParams.itemId)-1;
    } else {
      $scope.prevItem = $scope.hash.length-1;
    }

    if ($routeParams.itemId < $scope.hash.length-1) {
      $scope.nextItem = Number($routeParams.itemId)+1;
    } else {
      $scope.nextItem = 0;
    }

  });
}]);
```

From my JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "tag":"#StandWithPP",
    "shortName":"StandWithPP",
    "longName":"Stand With Planned Parenthood",
    "firstUse":"January 2012",
    "numUses":"55.7",
    "origin":"On a Tuesday in January 2012, the Susan G. Komen Foundation, which annually contributed $680,000 to Planned Parenthood, announced in a largely political move that it planned to cut off that funding. By the Friday of that week, more than 100,000 people had tweeted in outrage, and Komen restored funding. The hashtag has only grown from there, taking over all major forms of social media, extending as far as dating apps such as OKCupid, which allows users to post a badge on their profile with the tag.",
    "category":"feminism",
    "widget":"<a class='twitter-timeline' data-dnt='true' href='https://twitter.com/hashtag/StandWithPP' data-widget-id='964987220951265280'>#StandWithPP Tweets</a><script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,'script','twitter-wjs');</script>"
  }
]
```

I've gone through several iterations of ways to call the information from the JSON and "trust" it, but none of the syntax I've found worked.

Update: I realized that the Twitter widget has enough consistency for me to use Angular markup to fill it in for each item in the JSON file.

Here's the new HTML:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-dnt="true" href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/{{hash[whichItem].shortName}}" data-widget-id="{{hash[whichItem].widget}}">{{hash[whichItem].tag}} Tweets</a>
            <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

And an example of one item from the associated JSON:

```
[
  {
    "tag":"#StandWithPP",
    "shortName":"StandWithPP",
    "longName":"Stand With Planned Parenthood",
    "firstUse":"January 2012",
    "numUses":"55.7",
    "origin":"On a Tuesday in January 2012, the Susan G. Komen Foundation, which annually contributed $680,000 to Planned Parenthood, announced in a largely political move that it planned to cut off that funding. By the Friday of that week, more than 100,000 people had tweeted in outrage, and Komen restored funding. The hashtag has only grown from there, taking over all major forms of social media, extending as far as dating apps such as OKCupid, which allows users to post a badge on their profile with the tag.",
    "category":"feminism",
    "widget":"964987220951265280"
  }
]
```

The good news is, it works! The bad news is, it doesn't load when you first load the partial. You have to wait several minutes and then refresh the page to get the actual timeline widget, rather than the simple link that is the error default. (And once you return to the list view, you have to repeat the process over again.)

At first, I assumed it was a problem with bringing in the JSON data, and tried with a simple copy-paste of the original widget markup to check. But even a script that wasn't using AngularJS expression binding markup failed initially. I realized that was a problem with Angular's built-in jquite not rendering inline script tags, so I added the jQuery library to fix it.

Now, the widget without the expression binding works fine on initial loading of the partial, but I'm still having to wait several minutes and reload in order for the customized widget to work! I assume this has something to do with the nature of AngularJS and the way it calls data. Is this a lost cause? Would fixing it defeat the purpose of using AngularJS?

Comment: Even with `$sce.trustAsHtml`, you are going to have issues rendering content that has `script` tags in it.  The entire point of the `$sce` is to stop malicious scripting, and quite frankly there should never be a reason to store HTML/scripts in variables.  It might be better if you try to describe your end result and ask about how to get the result in angular, rather than trying to go this route, where you try to bypass angular.

Comment: Dang. It's a Twitter widget, which is why it has the script. Unfortunately, based on the nature of the widgets, which each have individualized id numbers, I can't just describe the end goal. I'm trying to pull a different widget for each version of the details partial page, based on which item is being called from the JSON file.  Based on what you've said, I'm trying to simply replace the necessary pieces with info from the different widgets I've created, but it doesn't seem to work either. I'll keep at it.

Comment: Weird update: pulling the unique id numbers and tag searches from the widget info, I used angular markup to just change the necessary pieces. The weird part is, it only works the first time after I change the partial file (and even then, it only seems to work the first time the widget is displayed-- if I remove it, refresh, and then add it back it still fails), and then every time I try from thereon out, it fails, despite no console errors.

Answer (score 0):

Amanda, you are on a slippery road ;)
Your code is getting more and more complicated and requires complex solutions.

Most likely to solve your issue you would add a directive and your code will look like:

```
hashControllers.controller('DetailsController', function($scope) {
  $scope.whichItem =  {
    "tag":"#StandWithPP",
    "shortName":"StandWithPP",
    "longName":"Stand With Planned Parenthood",
    "firstUse":"January 2012",
    "numUses":"55.7",
    "category":"feminism",
    "widget":"<a class='twitter-timeline' data-dnt='true' href='https://twitter.com/hashtag/StandWithPP' data-widget-id='964987220951265280'>#StandWithPP Tweets</a><script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,'script','twitter-wjs');</script>"
  }
});

hashControllers.directive('widget', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var el = angular.element(scope.whichItem.widget); //create markup
        var compiled = $compile(el); //compile the view into a function.
        elem.append(el); // add it to view
        compiled(scope); // adding scope, you can actually pass variables to you templete here
    };
}]);
```

And template:

```
<div widget="{{whichItem.widget}}"></div>
```

I hope that will help, happy coding!